# Python : Avoid loading/reading data every time I run my code

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video

I am developing a program in Python that requires me to read 50 videos and 100 photos every time I run it.
I am using the library openCv to read the videos and the images.  Is there a way to avoid reloading the data every time ? Like store it in a cash memory or something ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you identify that the reading of the files is a bottleneck in your application by benchmarking ?

Comment: It could be that the time for decompression of the videos dominates and caching the video files would not help. And keeping all frames decompressed is probably out of question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `redis` to handle your caching: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

Additionally, if the load-time is your concern, check out Python's `multithreading` module. There's several tutorials out there on how to get started if you aren't familiar.

If this project is something you're invested in, multithreading could be a gamechanger for you. Especially as your sample increases.

Comment: the issue with redis I see is that you still have to move the data over sockets, and redis has to hold it in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

reading data, compressed or uncompressed, always takes time. time is spent on decompression and on I/O because of finite bandwidth.

if you think decompression is the significant time sink, you could unpack your data into an uncompressed file format (raw binary). then at least you don't have to spend time uncompressing it again. it *will* take more I/O bandwidth and storage of course.

when you have uncompressed data in a file, you can *memory-map* it. that maps the file into RAM instantly, and then you can access it however you like.

for pictures, I would suggest the [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) python package. it supports memory mapping, for some picture formats. I would suggest using this package to write image files so they are in the appropriate format.